# Microsoft Office 365 task over 10 seconds after I press ctrl-F to search text

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, office365

After I open a .doc, when I press ctrl-F to find something, the Navigation pane on the left annoyingly takes over 10-20 seconds to open.

After that, it opens right away.

Can anything be done to speed this up?

My Ethernet connection to Internet is over 100Mbps.

This is on Windows 10 64bit, and occurs on multiple laptops that I work with.

Comment: Sounds like you have some installed add-in that is bothering you. Check what you have in menu *File > Options > Add-ins* and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: In Word, go to View tab, in the Show group, directly select the box for "Navigation pane". Then search words to confirm if it is slow or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is occurring after an instance of the Word application is loaded into memory, then it probably has to do with document pagination. The document has to be fully scanned before the navigation function will work. The larger and more complex the document, the longer the pagination process will take. By complexity I mean, tables, inserted pictures, automation fields, tracked changes and comments, TOC, Indexes and Citations. One other factor that can slow the initial load of a document is font substitution. Make sure your document's are using the standard fonts.

If you are opening documents directly from Windows File Finder, and Word is not already open, then Word's need to load fonts, call home, load add-ins, etc. will add to the first document open delay time.

You mention running Windows 64bit but you don't mention the bit level of your Office version. A 64bit version of Office will be faster in some processes versus the 32bit version. However, with that said, your computer will need at least 8GB of RAM in order to take advantage of it.